# Azure B2C: How to check if strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber is persisting against the right object ID?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have the following custom policy TP for the phone verification step (which create a temp ID) for MFA.

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify">
      <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.phonefactor</Item>
        <Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <!-- <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserIdForMFA" />   -->
        <!-- toggle -->
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>

      <InputClaims>
        <!-- <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdForMFA" PartnerClaimType="UserId" /> -->
        <!-- toggle -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="UserId" />

        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
      </InputClaims>

      <OutputClaims>

        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="Verified.OfficePhone" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPhoneNumberEntered" PartnerClaimType="newPhoneNumberEntered" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-MFA" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

The next step in the journey is to save the phone number using the object id. But I don't think it is saving it!

Answer (score 0):

You can always read it back in another journey or use ms graph api to return the strongAuth attribute.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/resources/phoneauthenticationmethod?view=graph-rest-beta